# Showing spaces between bars in android

Tags: android, bar-chart

How to mention the spaces between the bars of a bar-chart in android?

[image]
Thanks in advance!..

Above the image will make you clear about my doubt.ie,.

The blue bars are actually not fit to the corresponding x-axis values,here are (Ord_1,Ord_2,Ord_3,Ord_4).

I need to show these bars fitted with the x-axis values.How to do this?

Please find my sources below

**BarChart.java**

```
public class BarChart extends Activity 
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = createIntent();
    startActivity(intent);
}

public Intent createIntent() 
{
    String[] titles = new String[] { "Profits per order", " " };

    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();

    values.add(new double[] { 6, 9, 21, 3 });
    values.add(new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 0});


    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK };

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
    renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

    setChartSettings(renderer, "Profit of the year 2012", " ", " ", 0,30, 0,30, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);

    renderer.setXLabels(1);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);

    renderer.addXTextLabel(2.75, "Ord_1");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(6.75, "Ord_2");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(10.75, "Ord_3");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(14.75,"Ord_4");

    renderer.setBarSpacing(-1.75);

    int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
      SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
      seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
    }

    return ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,
        Type.DEFAULT);
  }

protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) 
{

    // creates a SeriesRenderer and initializes it with useful default values as well as colors

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);

    int length = colors.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
      SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
      r.setColor(colors[i]);
      renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
    return renderer;
  }

protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,
          String yTitle, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,
          int labelsColor) 
{
// sets lots of default values for this renderer

    renderer.setChartTitle(title);
    renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
    renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
    renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);
    renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);

    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);


}

protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<double[]> values) 
{

    // adds the axis titles and values into the dataset

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    int length = titles.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
      CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);
      double[] v = values.get(i);
      int seriesLength = v.length;

      for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) 
      {
        series.add(v[k]);
      }
      dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
     }
    return dataset;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `setChartSettings` with some parameters that set the X axis visual range between 0 and 30 and the same for the Y axis. You can tweak these parameters for having a better relaxed display.

You are calling `renderer.setBarSpacing()` with a negative value. Just use a positive one, start with `0.5f` (which means the spacing being equal to half the bar thickness) and then tweak it based on your needs.