# how can i implement bar chart

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, achartengine

i want to display bar chart in android app using some free chart engine which is suitable.
this is how i am excepecting the graph to be:

I am trying to make with following features.

Add onclick to each bar(red,blue,green).

Display the legend on top instead of bottom.

In Y axis it displays values I want to display 1 - 200.

And onlick display the values on top of each bar.

[image]

i have looked into `Achart engine` but it does not have a bar chart like this.

please help me on this.

Comment: You haven't looked enough. You can use AChartEngine to build such chart.

Comment: However, you are using a locally modified version of AChartEngine, which makes it hard for anyone to help you with AChartEngine related issues.

Comment: @Dan no i can use your copy now as i am working on new android app and need not want to modify if all the features are present so please help me

Comment: See the answer I have up-voted. That will help you.

Comment: @Dan ok the first link in that right ?

Comment: @Dan hi i think it works fine but now i need your help could you please help me

Comment: @Dan are you there can you please help me

Comment: @Dan ok shall we move this to chat room? i have just started with it

Comment: 1) how to give space between each series 2) scroll only horizontal right. i have tried with mrenderer.setBarSpacing(0); but not working
3)custom labels on y axis now it shows 0,5,10 i need toprovide myown values

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153871/showing-spaces-between-bars-in-android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

refer this. I think this will help you. 
 http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-bar-chart-using-achartengine/

[`Bar Chart in Android With out any Built in jars`](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/bar-chart-in-android-with-out-any-built-in-jars/)

Comment: hey it looks like what i wanted i need some more help from you on this

Comment: @Goofy I dont know more but will try

Comment: have you implemented that?

Comment: how to disable it from moving to top and it should only move to right now its moving to left also can you please help me

Comment: how to give space between after each series

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153871/showing-spaces-between-bars-in-android

Comment: hey thanks will look into that and please help me on these issues also 1) scroll only horizontal right. i have tried with mrenderer.setBarSpacing(0); but not working 2)custom labels on y axis now it shows 0,5,10 i need toprovide myown values

Comment: renderer.addYTextLabel(10, "here give ur value instead of 10");

Comment: yes now the graph moves to top, bottom,left and right. i hope you got my point

Comment: u told u want to add labels r8?

Answer (score 2):

I did this with [MPAndroiChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). For complete solution, please refer my [MPAndroidChart-barchart](https://github.com/shuwnyuantee/MPAndroidChart-barchart) project in Github.

Here's the outcome:

[image]

Here's some code snippet for **Bar Chart**:

```
mChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

final ArrayList<BarEntry> bar1List = new ArrayList<>();
final ArrayList<BarEntry> bar2List = new ArrayList<>();
final ArrayList<BarEntry> bar3List = new ArrayList<>();
final ArrayList<String> xLabels = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    bar1List.add(new BarEntry(i, (float) randInt()));
    bar2List.add(new BarEntry(i, (float) randInt()));
    bar3List.add(new BarEntry(i, (float) randInt()));

    xLabels.add("entry " + i);
}

BarDataSet bar1Set = new BarDataSet(bar1List, "Bar 1");
bar1Set.setColor(bar1Color);
bar1Set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
bar1Set.setDrawValues(false);

BarDataSet bar2Set = new BarDataSet(bar2List, "Bar 2");
bar2Set.setColor(bar2Color);
bar2Set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
bar2Set.setDrawValues(false);

BarDataSet bar3Set = new BarDataSet(bar3List, "Bar 3");
bar3Set.setColor(bar3Color);
bar3Set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
bar3Set.setDrawValues(false);

// (0.20 + 0.05) * 3 + 0.25 = 1.00 -> interval per "group"
final float groupSpace = 0.25f;
final float barSpace = 0.05f;
final float barWidth = 0.2f;

BarData barData = new BarData(bar1Set, bar2Set, bar3Set);
barData.setBarWidth(barWidth);

// make this BarData object grouped
barData.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace); // start at x = 0

mChart.setData(barData);

mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
mChart.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
mChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
mChart.setPinchZoom(false);
mChart.setScaleEnabled(false);

// show legend on Top Left
Legend legend = mChart.getLegend();
legend.setEnabled(true);
legend.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
legend.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
legend.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP);

YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
leftAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
leftAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
leftAxis.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
// show range: 0 -> 200
leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(200);

XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
xAxis.setTextSize(12);
xAxis.setAxisMaximum(barData.getXMax() + 1);
xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-40f);

IAxisValueFormatter xAxisFormatter = new IAxisValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        if (value >= 0 && value <= xLabels.size() - 1) {
            return xLabels.get((int) value);
        }

        // to avoid IndexOutOfBoundsException on xLabels, if (value < 0 || value > xLabels.size() - 1)
        return "";
    }
};

xAxis.setValueFormatter(xAxisFormatter);

// display value during highlight
YMarkerView mv = new YMarkerView(this);
mv.setChartView(mChart);    // For bounds control
mChart.setMarker(mv);       // Set the marker to the chart

mChart.invalidate();
```

To **display value when bar is clicked**, I implemented **custom MarkerView**:

```
package com.example.shuwnyuan.barchart;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.MarkerView;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.MPPointF;


/**
 * Custom implementation of the MarkerView.
 *
 * @author Shuwn Yuan Tee
 */
public class YMarkerView extends MarkerView {
    private TextView tvContent;

    public YMarkerView(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_marker_view);
        tvContent = findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
    }

    // callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
    // content (user-interface)
    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
        tvContent.setText("" + (int)e.getY());

        super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
    }

    @Override
    public MPPointF getOffset() {
        return new MPPointF(-(getWidth() / 2), -getHeight());
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: You saved me 2 days work. Thanks a lot